# Vim Stuck In Insert Mode

Tags: linux, vim, putty

I've been using Vim for several months now via my web host (they allow putty access). All of a sudden, the `escape` key has become unresponsive. I cannot exist insert or any other mode by simply hitting escape. I have to hit `F1` which brings up the help in vim and kicks me into command mode.

I'm most certain that my escape key on my keyboard is functioning fine since all of my windows shortcuts that use the escape key operate normally.

I know this is a ridiculous question and I'm certain there's a lot more to look into regarding a solution. What I really need is a solid lead as to where to start looking.

Things that might help:

1. I'm using vim via putty
2. I'm logging in using jailshell
3. I'm not root

Comment: what are your terminal settings?  ie what exactly is the TERM environment variable set to (in the remote shell)?

Comment: $TERM is set to 'xterm'

Comment: Does `Ctrl-[` work? What do you get if you press `Ctrl-v` then escape? It should show as `^[`.

Comment: The Ctrl-[ worked. Rock on! This saves me a lot of frustration. Is there any chance you can explain why `esc` no longer works? Also, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: My first thought when reading this: "Oh he broke his 'Get me the heck out of here' button"

Comment: this just happened to me after a fresh install of gvim: turns out I was in gvim-easy … which is not so easy if you expect it to behave like vim.

Comment: Today I was stuck in insert mode then I realized that mistakenly configured a shortcut on my konsole profile for ESC key...

Comment: This sometimes happens to me: accidentally freezing Vim, in a xfce4-terminal (it's actually the terminal that is frozen). Various xon-xoff solutions (Ctrl-Q ...) had no effect. Although no keyboard shortcut was evident, I noticed that from the terminal menu that the terminal had become set to "Read-Only." Unchecking that restored terminal responsiveness.

Comment: Your question was my answer, thanks. On Mac Terminal, ESC and `CTRL+q` had no effect. Your F1 trick helped me get back to command mode so I could quit.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try using `Ctrl-[` instead of `Esc`.

What is the result of:

```
python -c "print ord(raw_input('char '))"
```

when you press `Esc` and `Enter`? It should be "27". What is the result of pressing `Ctrl-V` then `Esc`?

Have you checked all the settings in PuTTY to see if they're reasonable?

Are you using Bash on the remote system? Look at the output of

```
bind -p | grep -i '\\e' | less
```

and see if you see anything unusual. Do you have a file called `~/.inputrc`? Look at its contents to see if anything is unusual.

Look at your `~/.vimrc` and see if everything's OK, too.

Comment: Ctrl-c should end insert-mode as well (the '[' is sometime a bit tricky to get on some keyboards)

Comment: I ran the python script and it came back as an empty string. How do I fix this? I'm using putty.

Comment: @Keith: Did you try any of the other diagnostic suggestions?

Comment: ctrl+[ worked for me for whatever reason, no idea what i did to get my vim stuck.

Comment: `python -c "print(ord(input('char ')))"` for people with python3

Comment: [`Ctrl C`](https://superuser.com/a/1704820/1276192)

Answer (score 226):

I had mistakenly hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>, and got stuck in the insert mode. To get out of it use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: That's not insert mode that's [`XOFF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control). You can disable software flow control by doing `stty -ixon` (add it to your `~/.bashrc`). Then that keystroke will be available to be bound to something else. By default in Bash it's bound to `forward-search-history` (the opposite of Ctrl-r). Ctrl-q (Bash `quoted-insert`) will also be available.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Wouldn't `.bash_profile` be a better place? There's no need to turn it off in non-interactive shell, is it?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: ["When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists."](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) `.bash_profile` is only executed when Bash is a login shell. "So, typically, your ~/.bash_profile contains the line `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi`"

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You are right. What I meant to say is that there's probably sense to disable software flow control only in interactive shells. If this is true then subsequently it would make sense to find a way to tell if a shell is interactive and disable software flow control only in this case.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: See [my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/146747/1293) to "How can I check in bash if a shell is running in interactive mode?"

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you are using the [*insert mode*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27insertmode%27).

> 'insertmode' 'im' 'noinsertmode' 'noim'
>   boolean (default off)
>   Makes Vim work in a way that Insert mode is the default mode.  Useful if you want to use Vim as a modeless editor.  Used for |evim|.
>   [...]
>       - Use <kbd>CTRL-O</kbd> to execute one Normal mode command |i_CTRL-O|).  When
>         this is a mapping, it is executed as if 'insertmode' was off.
>         Normal mode remains active until the mapping is finished.
>       - Use <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> to execute a number of Normal mode commands, then use
>         <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get back to Insert mode.  Note that <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd> moves the cursor
>         left, like  does when 'insertmode' isn't set.  |i_CTRL-L|

I suggest editing `~/.vimrc` to add the following line:

```
set noinsertmode         "disable insert mode
```

Comment: In my case it stuck in insert mode because i had accidentally used ` -y ` in commandline
As said in manual:

       -y          Start Vim in easy mode, just like the executable was called "evim" or "eview".  Makes Vim behave like a click-and-type editor.

To exit this "ease mode" just use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> (L lowercase) as said by +SandRock

Comment: I accidently entered :set insertmode
CTRL-L got me out of it.

Comment: I changed a command line from `diff -y` (side-by-side) to `vimdiff -y` and then wondered what was going on.

Answer (score 8):

Find a strange way to quit:

> copy some thing and paste it, then you can use `<esc>` or `<ctrl-c>` or `<ctrl-[>` to quit

see gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBnns.gif

Comment: I had one vim session in a tmux pane start acting weirdly after accessing it via SSH from Windows - everything else, including other vim sessions in the same tmux session, were totally fine. `ctrl+c` etc. didn't work, but this did.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. All the others didn't. I'm using iterm2, mosh, and tmux. Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but realized it was from accidentally changing the SCIM input mode to "Other - RAW CODE".  I changed it back to English/Keyboard and did not have any more problems.

Comment: While it wasn't SCIM for me, I had the same problem and it was fixed by launching the Gnome Language Settings dialog, which detected something wasn't installed correctly. After fixing that and rebooting my escape key worked again.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer didn't work for me here and even `ctrl + c` couldn't get me out. If yours is as stuck as mine, here's what worked for me:

1. Closed the current stuck terminal.
2. Reconnected with a new terminal.
3. Opened the file with Vim
4. Got a notice that it was already being edited.
5. It gave me the option of `R` for recovery which I chose.
6. Back into vim for the file without issue.

Comment: Ctrl+S then :q! worked for me. Not sure what happened.